# Finding difference between two rasters using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, land-cover, change-detection

I know how to find difference between two rasters with Spatial Analyst tools, but how to display attributes, for example differences between two Corine Land (2006 - 2012) rasters, how to see codes of Corine Land that change from year 2006 to 2012.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to identify which class becomes what then have a look at the Tabulate Area (Spatial Analyst) tool in the Help file. It generates an output table showing you the number of pixels which you can easily convert to area.

Comment: Yes I'm exactly asking for classes of Landcover become after finding differences between rasters. but with this tool calculate area from two rasters. I want to identify codes of Landcover afteer calculating differences between rasters.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and show an image/sketch of what you want as it is unclear what you are asking.